# Compiling classicthesis with LuaLaTex

Tags: luatex, classicthesis

I am using the package classicthesis (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/classicthesis?lang=de). Compiling the sample file included in the package with pdflatex works fine for me. Since my document includes several large pgfplots, I will ultimately need to compile the file with lualatex.

Trying to compile the sample file with lualatex, however, results in a lot of "undefined control sequence" errors.

Any guidance on how to adjust the config file for lualatex would be highly appreciated.

Comment: if you asking about an error always show the exact error that you get, as copied from the log file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd just use the classicthesis.sty and classicthesis-config.tex from https://bitbucket.org/amiede/classicthesis/src/?at=develop
The old files have some unnecessarily hard-coded pdflatex dependencies.